# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, edit

So i am trying to make an update with vuex but everytime I click on update button , I get this error : [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
found in
--->  at src/views/leads/editClient.vue
this is my code in editClient.vue :

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <PageHeader :title="title" :items="items" />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Edit  </h4>
            <p class="card-title-desc"></p>
            <form class="needs-validation" @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>First name</label>
                      <input
                      :value="Client.firstName"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input
                      :value="Client.lastName"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Enter Last name"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Email</label>
                   <input
                    :value="Client.email"
                    placeholder="insert email"
                    type="email"
                    class="form-control"
                  />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                     <input
                    :value="Client.phone"
                    placeholder="phone"
                    type="number"
                    class="form-control"
                  />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input
                      :value="Client.city"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="City"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input
                      :value="Client.country"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Country"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Gender</label>
                   <select :value="Client.gender" class="form-control"
                   >
                      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                      <option>Female</option>
                      <option>Male</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
                @click="update()"
                >Update</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end card -->
      </div>
      <!-- end col -->
     
      <!-- end col -->
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
    
  </Layout>
</template>

<script>
import Layout from "../../components/layouts/main";
import PageHeader from "../../components/page-header";
import appConfig from "@/app.config";
/* import Swal from "sweetalert2";
 *//* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable vue/no-dupe-keys */
import {
  required,
  
} from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

/**
 * Form validation component
 */
export default {
   props: ["id"],
  page: {
    title: "Edit Client",
    meta: [{ name: "description", content: appConfig.description }],
  },
  components: { Layout, PageHeader },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Edit Client",
      items: [
        {
          text: "leads",
          href: "/",
        },
        {
          text: "Edit",
          active: true,
        },
      ],      
      autoClose: "",          
      submitted: true,
      submitform: true,
      submit: true,
      typesubmit: true,
    };
  },
  validations: {
      Client: {
      firstName: { required },
      lastName: { required },
      email: { required },
      phone: { required },
      city: { required },
      country: { required },
      gender: { required },
    }, 
    value: null,
    value1: null,
    selected: ""
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("leadModule", ["leads"]),
    Client() {
      return this.leads.find((lead) => lead._id === this.id);
    },
   },
   created() {
      this.id = this.$route.params.id
    console.log("hello", this.getLeads);
    console.log("leadsss", this.leads);
    this.getLeads();
  },
  methods: {
     ...mapActions("leadModule", ["getLeads"]),    
     formSubmit() {
      this.submitted = true;
     },
     update() {
      this.submitted = true;
      this.$v.$touch();
    // if (this.$v.employe.$pending || this.$v.employe.$error) return;
      console.log('i am in form submit action')
      this.$store.dispatch("leadModule/updateLead", {
          firstName: this.Client.firstName,
          lastName: this.Client.lastName,
          email: this.Client.email,
          phone: Number(this.Client.phone),
          city: this.Client.city,
          country: this.Client.country,
          gender: this.Client.gender,
        }).then(()=>{
        console.log('dispatch actionnnn',this.Client.firstName),
        this.$router.push("leads")})
        Swal.fire("Done!", "Client updated successfully!", "success");
         console.log('Client updated');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and this is my moduleActions:

```
async updateLead({ commit }, payload) {
    console.log('i am in update functionnnnnnnnnn')
    try {
      console.log('enter try')
      const { data } = await apolloClient.mutate({
        mutation: UPDATE_LEAD,
        variables: payload
      });
      console.log('after updatedddddd')
      console.log("updatedLead", data.updateLead);

      commit("UPDATE_LEAD", data.updateLead);
      commit("setLoading", false);
    } catch (error) {

    commit("setLoading", false);
    commit("setError", error);
    }
  },
```

and my moduleMutations

```
 UPDATE_LEAD(state, payload) {
    console.log('I am in updated mutation')
    console.log("payload", payload);
    const index = state.leads.findIndex(lead => lead._id === payload);

    console.log("index", index);
    Vue.set(state.leads, index, payload);
  },
```

any suggestion will be appreciated
thank you

Comment: Does this line `console.log('i am in form submit action')` execute?

Comment: no it doesn't. 
i just get these errors 
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

found in

---> <EditClient> at src/views/leads/editClient.vue 

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

Comment: Comment out `this.$v.$touch();` and see. What does that function do?

Comment: but if i comment this line //this.$v.$touch(); this is what I get, 
I get this line( console.log("updatedLead", data.updateLead);
) ==> updatedLead null and  (console.log("payload", payload); ) ==> payload null

Comment: i get index -1 as well

Comment: ok so this line is the culprit right? `this.$v.$touch();`
What does this line do? Where does it come from?

Comment: i use vuelidate that's why .. to deal with data validation. 
import {
  required,
} from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

Comment: Do you have `Vue.use(Vuelidate)` in your App.js file?

Comment: yes i have that